# Download Listener Webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm using download listener to handle downloading files in webview. It works fine when i test with android 7 phones but it keeps downloading .bin files when i used android 9 phones

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                            long contentLength) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));

                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                    final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    if (dm != null) {
                        dm.enqueue(request);
                    }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make webView Download listner like this:

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                        long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                        mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: it is still downloading .bin file

Comment: Can you please share url of downlad file or which file you are downloading?

Comment: I'm downloading audio files and pdf files from google drive. I have created the downloadable url and stored the url at Firebase database

Comment: Try to follow this link:http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2013/11/download-file-videoaudiotext-through.html